# codeigniter mysql query to multidimensional array(nested list)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Ok here is what I am struggling  with.

I have  drop down menu on my site which is basically a nested list. It gets its information from my database. Now I have made this work as a procedural piece of code but I am now trying to separate it out for a MVC framework. Now my thinking is that if I use the model to get the information from the table pass that on to the controller as an multidimensional array and the pass it out to the view where I will then access the array to fill out the list. I need (or think I do) do it this way so that when I create another view for mobile devices I can reformat it to suit.

Down to the nitty gritty.

***table 'sch_cat'***

sch_cat_uid (primery{parent id}),

sch_cat_id,

sch_cat_order,

sch_cat_name.

***table `sch_subcat`***

sch_subcat_uid,

sch_subcat_order,

sch_subcat_name,

sch_subcat_href.

sch_subcat_parent (reference 'shc_cat_uid' from table 'sch_cat' )

The main focus here is putting the information to the array but I really don'y know where to begin here so any and pointers appreciated oh and if I am well of base don't feel  shy in calling me a plumb!.

Cheers
Troy

Comment: There are many similar related questions here on SO. Often for navigation lists. You could browse around a little and read, because your questions covers multiple parts like querying, creating a data-structure and the view part.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I can pretty much handle the view and control side if I can get the data into an array. I do have this working in procedural code but that pretty much builds a HTML list with loops. I was more asking than in MVC would it be better to send the information out from the Model as one multidimensional array. Then pass the array from the controller to the view where I can then build the list as I previously did it in my procedural code. Oh and the Main question is the first part how to get the queries to a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into using CodeIgniters [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) class?

As for querying data from a database with the class, you can easily make it come back the way you're looking for, I believe the particular function you're looking for is [result_array()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html).

Regarding the MVC practice, it's sufficient to have the querying of these items be in a model, that the controller grabs and passes to the proper view.